# Как получить полный путь к файлу или программе Windows? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как получить полный путь к файлу или программе в Windows, для его/ее дальнейшего открытия с помощью subprocess?

Comment: можете уточнить суть вопроса и привести примеры? что вам известно о файле / программе ?

Comment: @MaxU, у меня есть приложение, возьмём условный Google Chrome. На вход функции нужно дать имя программы, а на выходе получить полный путь к ней. Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: путь к этой программе прописан в переменной окружения `PATH`?

Comment: @MaxU, нет. Нужно добавить?

Comment: я не просто так попросил уточнить вопрос... Если это программа которая открывает определенный тип файлов по умолчанию в Windows, то данную информацию можно найти в реестре Windows. Если к данной программе прописан путь в переменной `PATH` - тоже можно найти. В противном случае придется искать данный файл во всех папках всех доступных дисков - это ОЧЕНЬ медленно

Comment: @MaxU, так и думал, что поиск займет достаточное количество времени. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: т.е. ваша программа __не__ находится в `PATH` и __не__ является зарегистрированной программой по умолчанию в Windows?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103273/discussion-between-lian-and-maxu).

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath("mydir/myfile.txt"))

'C:/example/cwd/mydir/myfile.txt'
```

Позаимствовал тут
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51520/how-to-get-an-absolute-file-path-in-python